# Cordova build: Command failed with exit code 8

Tags: facebook, cordova

I am building a phone gap (Cordova 3.5) app for android and trying to implement facebook login. I have installed the facebook plugin then i was getting errors in connectPlugin.java file then i imported the facebook SDK library in my project. All errors showing in eclipse are gone now but when i am trying to run 'cordova build' the build fails with the following error.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\android-tool\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occu
executing this line:
D:\android-tool\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 12 seconds

D:\xampp\htdocs\android-app\refund_app\platforms\android\cordova\node
q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\xampp\
oid-app\refund_app\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-D
e.dir=ant-gen
Error: D:\xampp\htdocs\android-app\refund_app\platforms\android\cordo
t: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself actually the build was failing due to a invalid directory in facebook SDK 
Mypath/facebook-android-sdk-3.23.0\facebook\bin\res\crunch
I cut all the contents from the 'crunch' folder and pasted it under 'res' folder then deleted the 'crunch' folder. Then cordova build started working.